# Maintaining Subject emission order when invoking next within subscription

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm running into a bug and I've determined it's due to the fact that Subjects when `next()`ed will fire their events synchronously.

The following code produces the following ouput:

```
mySubject.subscribe(score => {
  if (score === 2) {
    mySubject.next(score + 10);
  }
})
mySubject.subscribe(score => console.log(score))

Ouput:
1
12
2
```

The only way Im able to get the proper output (`1,2,12`) is if I wrap my `next()` call in a `setTimeout` to make it async.  Is there a proper way to deal with this issue that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using RxJS 5.5 I'd personally use `setTimeout` as well. There's `subscribeOn` operator that you could use with the `async` scheduler (`import { async } from 'rxjs/scheduler/async'`) to run every emission in a new frame but it's [not available in RxJS 5.5 right now](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/5.5.6/src/operators.ts#L79-L85).

So probably the easiest way is using `delay(0)` which doesn't make any delay and passes everything asynchronously like you did with `setTimeout()`:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

const mySubject = new Subject();
const source = mySubject.pipe(delay(0));

source.subscribe(score => {
  if (score === 2) {
    mySubject.next(score + 10);
  }
})
source.subscribe(score => console.log(score));

mySubject.next(1);
mySubject.next(2);
```

See live demo (open console): https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fiwgrk?file=index.ts

Comment: Thank you! Is nexting within a subscription an anti-pattern?

Comment: To be honest I think it usually is but this really depends on what you need to do. Maybe there really isn't a better way to do it. Often if you need to conditionally turn one emission into two you can use something like this `concatMap(score => score === 2 ? of(score, score + 10) : of(score))`

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
const plusTen$ = mySubject.filter(score => score === 2).map(score => score + 10);

mySubject.merge(plusTen$).subscribe(score => console.log(score))
```

Comment: That does satisfy the output. Ideally, I'd like `mySubject` to emit the values. But you did get me thinking about somehow putting a piece of "middleware" into the subject to modify the emission. Something like, 
`mySubject$ = mySubject.map(MAPPING_FUNCTION)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it helps the OP, but to anyone who encounters this situation:

It's strictly speaking not a bug because when you next() a Subject, all subscribers are iterated and called. So if you next() within the first subscriber, the iteration starts again and the second subscriber of the first iteration is called after the second iteration is done.

Note that because of this, the order of subscription is relevant. So alternatively to using setTimout or delay as suggested in the accepted answer, you could also swap the subscriptions like this:

```
mySubject.subscribe(score => console.log(score));
mySubject.subscribe(score => {
  if (score === 2) {
    mySubject.next(score + 10);
  }
})

Output:
1
2
12
```